# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`learn_backend`.`uer_role`, C

Tags: sql, spring

I am trying to do role based authentication from data base . i have established a many to many relationship for user and role .
I am trying to use the @EnableMethodSecurity in security config and      @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" in userController also tried using    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')"
still i am getting the errror

i tried using new version  @EnableMethodSecurity